# function orderInfo.Selected is not regconized

Tags: c#, excel, office-2007

I'm implementing the code from the book to create a customized action pane in Excel

```
using System;
```

using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeTools.Interop.Runtime;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace ExcelWorkbook1
{
  public partial class Sheet1
  {
    public Button customerButton = new Button();
    public Button inventoryButton = new Button();

```
private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  customerButton.Text = "Select a customer...";
  inventoryButton.Text = "Check inventory...";

  this.orderInfo.Selected +=
    new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(
    OrderInfo_Selected);

  this.orderInfo.Deselected +=
    new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(
    OrderInfo_Deselected);

  this.customerInfo.Selected +=
    new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(
    CustomerInfo_Selected);

  this.customerInfo.Deselected +=
    new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(
    CustomerInfo_Deselected);
}

#region VSTO Designer generated code
private void InternalStartup()
{
  this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(Sheet1_Startup);
}
#endregion

void OrderInfo_Selected(Excel.Range target)
{
  Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(inventoryButton);
}

void OrderInfo_Deselected(Excel.Range target)
{
  Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Remove(inventoryButton);
}

void CustomerInfo_Selected(Excel.Range target)
{
  Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(customerButton);
}

void CustomerInfo_Deselected(Excel.Range target)
{
  Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Remove(customerButton);
}
```

}
}

However
the code `this.order.Selected' is not regconized`
Do you have any suggestion for me?
Thanks

Comment: you are missing some code, what are orderInfo and customerInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a named range in your Sheet1 with name orderInfo?
If yes, is it generated in the code-behind? (Sheet1.Designer.cs)

Notice, that you misspeled the name of your member in the last sentence: should be 'this.orderInfo.Selected'